# Cannot Pivot DataFrame, No Unique Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe which is like below.

```
     ATTR1  ATTR2  ATTR3  UnitType    Value    Date
  0  1       2      3     TotalSales  10       10/2020
  1  1       2      3     Canceled    1        10/2020
  2  1       2      3     Returned    3        10/2020
  3  3       2      1     TotalSales  10       10/2020
  4  3       2      1     Canceled    1        10/2020
  5  3       2      1     Returned    3        10/2020
```

Data continues with different months. I want to make Date only 1 row for each attr1-2-3 combination and make new columns for each unit type.

I tried pivot function like below but it didn't work.

```
data.pivot(index=['Date', 'ATTR1', 'ATTR2', 'ATTR3'], columns='UnitType', values='Value')
```

It gives the following error.

```
Length of passed values is 1346544, index implies 4
```

Comment: Check out question 10 in the linked duplicate and add a unique cumcounted index to pivot with.

Comment: actually, it ididn't worked for me. I have multiple columns but it makes the example for one column. @cs95

Comment: What exactly do you want the final result to look like?

Comment: actually I solved it. I needed to use set_index() before using pivot. @itprorh66

Comment: If you solved it, post your solution as an answer and mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, there were already index columns in my dataframe and pivot indexes are not the same for my case. I was using different columns while melting and using extra column while pivoting. So, I needed to use `set_index()` and set my pivot parameters as index. Then it worked.